# How to stop NoSuchElementException error from this part of the code?

Tags: java, exception, encapsulation, nosuchelementexception

This is a section of my code from a project that is giving an error. I am practicing encapsulation, but, cannot figure out why I am getting this error when I am setting values inside the Array-list.

There are two classes

1) Create_accountant

2) Adminstoreroom

Both of them are under same package: `com.admin`

```
package com.admin;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Create_accountant {

Adminstoreroom admin = new Adminstoreroom();

void Creating() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t Create New Accoutant");
    System.out.println();
    name();
    pass();

}

void name() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter his/her name: \t");
    String name = null;

    try {
        admin.setAccName(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("done");
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Please enter the name again.");
        name();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Here is the main problem " + e);
    }
    admin.setAccName(name);
    input.close();
}

private void pass() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Enter his/her password: \t");

    try {
        admin.setAccPassword(input.nextLine());
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Please enter the password again.");
        pass();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Here is the main problem");
    }
    input.close();
}
```

The problem is inside the 2 try blocks.

```
try {
        admin.setAccName(input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

Both of the `name()` and `pass()` go for the catch(exception e) block. When I run this code, the output from the above try is

> Here is the main problem `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`

The second class

```
package com.admin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Adminstoreroom {


//These arrays are used for Storing accountant info in the admin sections
private static ArrayList<String> accName = new ArrayList<String>(30);
private static ArrayList<String> accPassword = new ArrayList<String>(30);

//Accountant Names
public void setAccName(String an) {
    accName.add(an);
}
public String getAccName(int i) {
    return accName.get(i);
}

//Accountant Password
public void setAccPassword(String ap) {
    accPassword.add(ap);
}
public String getAccPassword(int i) {
    return accPassword.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you can post the full error Stacktrace. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: it was a good decision to delete that other question about Class.forName(). But two comments: A) you should understand that forName() is about reflection. And reflection is a **very advanced** topic in the Java book of topics. Meaning: if you really didn't understand that simple syntax problem you should rather learn about Java basics - instead of starting to use reflection. Reflection is *hard* for people that know about Java, for people lacking basics it will be just one big frustrating serious of stuff not working.

Comment: B) looking at your history of posting it seems that you are rather going backwards. You already have questions where you put up source code, but now you asked one that had a screenshot. Please understand that asking "bad" questions repeatedly can get you **banned** from asking at some point. So please: not only learn basic java, also learn **how** to ask here. Otherwise your next questions will be frustrating for you, again and again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @GhostCat. I really appreciate that you spent your time in correcting my mistakes.

Comment: You are much more experienced in Java than me. Can I ask, like from where did you started learning Java or how should I clear my basics problem? @GhostCat.

Comment: That is a broad topic :-) basically I starting my Java career 20+ years back. I was studying and our university was the first one outside the US working with Java. My major class was about compiler construction - and that leads to a certain attitude towards languages. Basically you strive to understand the inner structure and how things come together. Plus : I simply like the language. And at least half of my professional career allowed me to practice Java. My recommendation: get a good book or study the oracle tutorials - top to bottom. Then: start small...

Comment: Meaning : don't try to learn 5 new things at once. Many people start using an ide - and then they want to build a swing or JavaFX application that talks to databases. Etc. As said - I suggest to go slower - but instead go deeper. Really understand each word that you write down. Don't accept not understanding something. Read and learn - ask when you get stuck. Most importantly : find real or (2nd choice) remote people that review your code. You learn the most by others commenting your work. Codereview.stackexchange.com is one place for that....

Comment: But understand that these online communities have rules and expect quality input! When you found this helpful... Feel free to look around my answers or questions and vote here or there :-)